# aws cognito angular example: URIError: URI malformed

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I was trying out the aws cognito example app based on angular 2, and noticed the following error.

The app is https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart

When I try to browse to this app deployed at http://cognito.budilov.com/ from Chrome browser on my Android, I get the following error. Any ideas on what could be going on?

```
vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:148 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): URIError: 
URI malformed
URIError: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at Object.fromBits (sjcl.js:11)
at e.value (amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19)
at e.value (amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19)
at e.value (amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19)
at l.O7AO.l.isAuthenticated (main.fd38a9f….bundle.js:1)
at new l (main.fd38a9f….bundle.js:1)
at Ze (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:225)
at ze (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:225)
at On (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:239)
at _n (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:239)
at Object.Hn [as createRootView] (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:239)
at e.create (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:302)
at e.create (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:281)
at t.createComponent (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:302)
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at Object.fromBits (sjcl.js:11)
at e.value (amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19)
at e.value (amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19)
at e.value (amazon-cognito-identity.min.js:19)
at l.O7AO.l.isAuthenticated (main.fd38a9f….bundle.js:1)
at new l (main.fd38a9f….bundle.js:1)
at Ze (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:225)
at ze (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:225)
at On (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:239)
at _n (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:239)
at Object.Hn [as createRootView] (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:239)
at e.create (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:302)
at e.create (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:281)
at t.createComponent (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:302)
at v (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at p (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at p (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697
at t.invokeTask (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:281)
at t.invokeTask (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at e.runTask (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at a (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
at HTMLAnchorElement.invoke (vendor.f06d8c6….bundle.js:697)
```

UPDATE:

This works fine with the non minified version of aws cognito identity js file, but is still a problem with the minified version.

Comment: Same problem here, only appears in the latest versions of chrome android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of aws-cognito-sdk.js and amazon-cognito-identity.js solves the problem.

You can fetch them from this repository https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js